# Runtime Error 1004 (data type error from cells and user input)

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating VBA macro to demonstrate Intermediate Value Theorem. User enters degrees and coefficients of terms of polynomial. Terms are concatenated into Polynomial.

When I run this I get:

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> Application-defined or object-defined error

Code so far.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Function1()
Dim Polynomial As String
Dim Sign
Dim RowCounter As Integer
Dim Degree
Dim Coefficient
Dim Term As String
Dim Variable

MsgBox "Enter polynomial by terms."
Variable = InputBox("Enter variable (x, y, z, etc.).")
Degree = Cells(RowCounter, 1).Value 'A2 and down
RowCounter = 1

While Cells(RowCounter, 1).Value <> "" And Cells(RowCounter, 2).Value <> "" ' as long as there is a coefficient and degree
    If (Coefficient < 0) Then
        Sign = " - " ' if coefficient negative
        Else
            If Coefficient > 0 Then Sign = " + " ' if coefficient positive
    End If
    Term = Sign & Coefficient & Variable & "^" & Degree = Cells(RowCounter + 1, 3).Value ' C2 and down
    Polynomial = Polynomial & Cells(RowCounter, 3).Value
    MsgBox Polynomial
    RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: @pnuts error is right after Degree=Cells...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `Rowcounter` before `Degree = Cells(RowCounter, 1).Value`. Otherwise, you're calling Cells(0,1), which returns Error 1004.

```
RowCounter = 1
Degree = Cells(RowCounter, 1).Value
```